# Client side data to server side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use a JavaScript popup box (prompt) to get some user input on my website, and then do some more actions on the server-side based on what the user does.

The popup box is, for lack of words, popping up.

The following is the code that I have tried to use for this:

```
<div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
</div>
<script>
    function userInput() {
        var reason = prompt("Enter reason for deleting:", "");
        //User pressed okay but didn't type anything
        while (reason == "") {
            //Keeps cycling until reason given or cancel is hit
            reason = prompt("Enter reason for deleting:", "");
        }
        if (reason != "" && reason != "Code:CancelDelete") {
            //User typed something and hit okay
            document.getElementById('hidden').innerHTML = reason.toString();
            $('#deleteReason').val(reason.toString());
            $("#hidden").val(reason.toString());
        }
        else {
            //User hits cancel
            document.getElementById('hidden').nodeValue = "Code:CancelDelete";
        }
    }
</script>
```

The while loop in the script works for what I need it to do. The problem from what I can tell is trying to set the value of the HiddenField. I have tried the following ways:

- innerHTML
- innerText
- nodeValue

While looking into this, I have seen .value used a lot and have tried it myself but when I go to type *document.getElementById('hidden').value =*, there is no popup option or description for *.value*.

I have tested the server side code and so I know that works. It all comes down to getting the user input. Either way, here is an excerpt from the c# code:

```
string deleteReason = hidden.Value;
//string deleteReason = test.InnerHtml.ToString();
if (deleteReason.Equals("Code:CancelDelete"))
{

}
else if (!deleteReason.Equals("Code:CancelDelete") && !deleteReason.Equals(""))
{
```

More or less at a loss on this one.

**Update 1:**
Here is the html code generated on the client side browser(Firefox) for the hidden field:

```
<input name="ctl00$IndividualPageContent$hidden" 
id="IndividualPageContent_hidden" type="hidden">
```

Comment: What's the actual client-side HTML of the hidden field?

Comment: @David The little bit shown where I define the hidden field is the only bit that I have for it.

Comment: Take a look at the actual client-side HTML that gets generated.  The JavaScript code is going to interact with the HTML in the browser, not the ASP.NET server-side code.

Comment: @David Just to clarify, I can't use a asp based control to send the data to the server side? As in, I can change the text of a asp label and an html label, try to change both, but only the html based label will change?

Comment: @David Or am I way off in my interpretation?

Comment: That's not it at all.  The server-side code results in generated client-side HTML.  The JavaScript can then interact with that HTML.  And that HTML posts data back to the server which ASP.NET then translates back into server-side data/objects.  The JavaScript part happens *entirely* in the browser and is only aware of what's in the client-side HTML in the browser.  So when the client-side code isn't working as expected, the first step is to take a look at what that HTML actually is, just in case it's different from what you assume it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the value of an element with id 'hidden', but that's not the id of your hidden input.

The correct id is 'IndividualPageContent_hidden'.

Set the value like this instead:

```
document.getElementById('IndividualPageContent_hidden').value = 'Your value here';
```

Answer (score 2):

When you type an element ID on webform, the asp.net gives it a unique ID based on some things (Your form, your repeater, etc...)

If you want to use jQuery with this ID, you can use the ClientId prop.

Something like this:

```
if (reason != "" && reason != "Code:CancelDelete") {
            //If your server id= "hidden"
            ele = $("#<%= hidden.ClientID %>");
            ele.html() = reason.toString();
            ...
        }
```

Another option is to add the static ID to your server element, and then your code will work as is. (the html will be rendered with ID = hidden)

ClientIDMode="static"

```
<div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"/>
</div>
```